# Getting unique id for a form element in a table in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a table where i am using best in place to update an item. Every item in the table has that form element and all of them will have the same id. So When we update the attribute for one element all the elements will be updated with the same data.
How do i solve this issue. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Structure of the table :

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="spare_table">
      <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th> Price </th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @manufacturer.spares.each_with_index do |spare, index| %>
      <tr id="li_<%= spare.id.to_s %>">
        <td><%= spare.name %></td>
         <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2" id="add">
                            Show
                          </button>
   <div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><%= spare.name%></h4>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <b> Name : </b> <%= spare.name %> <br/> <br/>
        ...
       <% end %>

       </ul>
       </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
```

I have updated the structure of table. Here im displaying the details inside the modal, but all the spares will have the details of the first spare itself

Comment: ID must be unique.. why all these elements have the same ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show us the structure of the table and a pair of values to check if there're some unique value that you can check to identify. Maybe the name will be unique?

You always need to find a key that have non repeated values to identify a row of your table.

Comment: I refer table as database table :)
Regarding your code your spare have:
spare.name
spare.id

So if id are repeated the only way to identify is by name

Comment: hey i meant the java-script id? . for every row i am updating the quantity and since all the form elements will be on the same page all are getting updated with the same value.